# Is there a Java branch coverage tool which can tell you about the exact missing turns in branches?

Tags: java, code-coverage

I have used **JaCoco** for line coverage in a previous project. Although line coverage in **IClassCoverage** just gives you a **ICounter** which has only the counts just like the branch coverage, **IClassCoverage** inherits **ISourceNode** which has information for each line, which makes the line coverage a bit of special among the others. So the only way I can think of to match the branches in JaCoco is tampering the JaCoco instrumentation procedure which I think is over-killing. I'd rather use **Wala** to get the control flow graph and match the line coverage from JaCoco. Is there any tool that can tell me about the exact branches?

Comment: OK, we're going to repeat the vocabulary discussion we had at SO.  (You're making a mistake of not being careful about the rules for good questions).   What exactly are you looking for?   You need to provide a concrete example.

Comment: @IraBaxter Plz give me paper/book references to all YOUR literature so that I could tell you what I need in your words. Otherwise it would be endless.

Comment: Let's start with this page for basic vocabulary, and hope your request is one defined there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage    If not, I'll get out a bigger reference.  A concrete example would still be helpful.

Comment: @IraBaxter "Branch coverage - Has each branch (also called DD-path) of each control structure (such as in if and case statements) been executed?" Okay, so my question is: Is there any tool that can not only tell you whether each branch has been executed but also which branches have been executed?

Comment: @IraBaxter I have to assume you really really want to give me an answer but just really really don't think my question is clear enough. If not, I don't think you have to worry about other viewers.

Comment: You said "can not only tell you whether each branch has been executed but also which branches have been executed?"  Um, how are these two parts of your question different? If a tool knows whether a specific branch has been executed, it knows the set of all branches that have been executed, trivially by enumerating every branch and asking if it has been executed.  Here is a tool that knows exactly what branches have been covered; there's even a tab to select exactly that list. https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: ... also I'm a bit unsure about what you mean by "tell you about".   I've shown a GUI display, which is one kind of "tell you about".   You can imagine a log file which contains a list of source locations for branches (each branch as a range of lines), as another kind of "tell you about" (our SD tool provides that, too).

Comment: @IraBaxter Well, I am actually looking for something can literally "tell me about" it, by speaking words to my ears, not GUI thing. Anyway, excuse me for my not-so-good English. As I said in the question body, JaCoco cannot "know" about it because it's just counting probes when the tests  being executed. It does not track the branch info at the instrumentation stage. Again, if you are (or I am) very strict on "literature", according to the link you sent me, coverage only answers a yes/no question and does not have to tell you "which branches".

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for your knowledge and patience. Thanks for the pointer to your tool.

Comment: "yes/no" answers across a set of blocks of code *does* tell which blocks (go read about "characteristic vectors").  "The" tool answers this question; can you confirm it is what you want, or not?  I'm not sure how to interpret "speaking words to my ears"; you can't be serious?

Comment: @IraBaxter "The" tool is an acceptable answer. Really appreciate it. If you write it in the answer, I'll accept/confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a tool knows whether a specific branch has been executed, it knows the set of all branches that have been executed, trivially by enumerating every branch and asking if it has been executed.

Here is a tool (from my company) that knows exactly what branches have been covered; there's even a tab to select exactly that list.

http://semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html

It can also produce a list of covered branches, and the associated line numbers for each covered branch.